How can I keep a service alive as long as possible during the shutdown sequence?
I am trying to keep a service alive for as long as possible. This is to keep critical communications open to usb serial device for as long as possible. I am OK with this service being killed forcefully.
I have tried playing around with Before=Shutdown.target paired with DefaultDependencies=No, but that doesn't seem to have any impact. I am not sure I completely understand how these special case targets can be used in services, and the documentation does not explain the exact sequence of operations during shutdown very well.
So far the best I have managed that actually makes sense is to use Before=basic.target
[Unit]
Description=LONG LIFE SERVICE
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=basic.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=+/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/me/long_run_service.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


Is there any way to keep the service alive longer with the shutdown targets (or any other approaches)?
Thanks

Run it from /etc/rc.local so systemd doesn't know about it, and ignore all signals?  (so it'll eventually die with kill -9) ?  Just an idea!

Although I'm not completely sure, but AFAICT here, just DefaultDependencies=no will do exactly the job. With ExecStop=/usr/bin/sleep 10 in a testing service, I see no "stopping countdown" triggered in the shutdown process, and with Conflicts=shutdown.target and Before=shutdown.target (or After=; see systemd.unit(5) about Conflicts= for details) in addition, I can see it triggered by the sleep 10 at a very late stage (like after the umount of all other filesystem and the remount of the root filesystem). So perhaps the problem here isn't the service being stopped early?
